# Combining artwork into one pdf file with page numbers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I have to submit my digital folio for UNI selection.  The requirements are all of my designs have to be in ONE PDF file with page numbers and a brief description of what each piece represents.
I have no idea how to firstly save in one PDF, how to get page numbers for this and how to write a brief description of each piece.

Comment: Use a standard word processors (MS-Office, LibreOffice) and include your images in the text?

Comment: Do you have access to the full version of Acrobat?

Answer (score 1):

This is exceptionally easy to do with InDesign. You can compose each page separately and even place your final image as a `.PSD` or `.PDF` onto the page.

1. Open a new InDesign document with your country's standard paper size (mine is `LTR` since I'm in the US) with however many pages you need. Uncheck Facing Pages and hit ok.

[image]

2. Now we can create our page numbers so that they'll count up on their own. The video below shows how to go about doing this. If you need further instructions, you can read [this Adobe article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVmP9.gif) on how to set it up.

[image]

3. Again, working on your Master Page, you will create a Rectangular Frame. Now you will have a nice template on each page to insert your image into.

[image]

4. Finally, on the Master Page select the Rectangular Frame and under the options change fitting to *Fit Content Proportionally*. Now click on your first page and place your image into the frame and create a Text Frame to type out your description.

[image]